# Connect to an Oracle DB using ODBC

Tags: oracle, odbc

I am developing an application that needs to interract with a "lightly documented" Legacy Oracle Database. To Start that process I want to start creating a view into that Database using ODBC links into an MS Access database so I can figure out the DB structure but I can't figure out how to setup the ODBC connection to the Oracle DB.

I have been able to connect using the Host and Service Name to and view the DB using SQL Developer; but, I can't figure out how to setup ODBC. I am running Windows 7 and have installed Oracle 11g, Oracle Express Edition, the Instant Client and ODBC extensitons; but on the ODBC setup Oracle wants me to pick a TNS Service Name but there is none to pick and there is no place to specify the host.  I tried to setup a TNS in tnsnames.ora; but I am not really sure I know the right location for that file.

I really thought this would be the easy part; but, it really hasn't been.

Comment: `tnsnames.ora` will only be there if you have Oracle Client installed in your machine (i.e. if you can find SQLPLUS in your All programs).

Comment: I installed Oracle Client 11g (free). I don't think I have SQL*Plus.  I do have a tsnames.ora file under C:\app\hancockm\product\11.2.0\client_1\Network\Admin to contains the following (but with III, NNN, PPP, and SSS filled in)
III=
 (DESCRIPTION =    
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = NNN)(PORT = PPP))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = SSS) (UR=A))
 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to the **Control Panel** > **Administrative Tools** > **Data Sources (ODBC)**

Select the **System DSN** tab and click 'Add'.  Next scroll down the lists of drivers until you find **Microsoft ODBC for Oracle**.

[image]

Fill in the required information in the above form and click 'OK'.  Now you can add the tables to 'Access' by clicking on the 'External Data' tab then clicking on 'More'. Choose 'ODBC Databases', then 'Import the source data...', next click on the 'Machine Data Source' tab.

Comment: This looks like it is getting me there but I can't find out where to specify the Service Name.  When I tried to connect from Access I got 'TNS:listnere was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA' when I tried to do the import.

Comment: I moved off this some time ago; but in the process had to uninstall and re-install the Oracle Client on my PC so we count test the production setup procedure.  We did end up setting the Data Source as a System DNS and I just checked and I can access the Tables from MS Access.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option to generate the tnsnames.ora file is to let Oracle do it.  If you launch the Oracle Net Configuration Assistant (Start | Oracle in *Oracle Home Name* | Configuration and Migration Tools | Net Configuration Assistant), you should be able to choose "Local Net Service Name configuration" which allows you to add (or modify) a TNS alias.  That will walk you through gathering the information you'll need to connect.

If you are more comfortable dealing with the text files directly, you can directly edit the tnsnames.ora file in %Oracle Home%\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora using this as a template.

```
<TNS alias> = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <hostname or IP>)(PORT = <port>)) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SERVER = DEDICATED) 
      (SERVICE_NAME = <database service name>) 
    ) 
  )
```

Comment: I don't think I have the Net Configuration Assistant.
Regarding the tnsnames.ora, I had added it there but it did't seem to make any difference.
How can I verify the Oracle Home path?
Do I have to do anything or make the tnschanges take affect? (Ex: Reboot)

Comment: @markshancock - If you installed the Oracle database, the Net Configuration Assistant should have been installed.  You pick the Oracle Home path at install time.  You can look at the registry to figure out what Oracle Homes you have-- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\%Name of Oracle Home%\ORACLE_HOME` will have the path

Comment: I am just working on the client side.
I have not installed an Oracle Database, just the Client and XE.  The only item I have under Configuration and Migration Tools is Microsoft ODBC Administrator - which just takes me to the Windows ODBC Data Source Adminstrator.

I looked in the Registry for the Client and the path and file seem correct.

Answer (score 0):

In tnsnames.ora, try changing SERVICE_NAME to SID.  That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My Experience
1. TNSNAMES.ORA is as follows.
    XE =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = 
          (PROTOCOL = TCP)
          (HOST = 192.168.2.116)
          (PORT = 1521)
        )
      )
      (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
      )
    )

2. Set Windows Environment Variables (ControlPanel --> System --> Detail..) 
   2-1. Add to PATH
       c:\oraclexe\instantclient_11_2\   --- install directory of instantclient
   2-2. Add New Environment Variable
       TNS_ADMIN    c:\oraclexe\instantclient_11_2\ --> install directory 
       NLS_LANG = JAPANESE_JAPAN.JA16SJISTILDE
3. Windows command prompt
   cd c:\Windows\SysWow64  <--I use 32bit ODBC in 64bit Win7
   odbcad32.exe
   　  Name :         ICODBC <-- as you like
   Service Name : XE
   User Name:     system
   Press Connection Test Button