# How to add Oracle Spatial data to Quantum GIS

Tags: oracle, gis

I can't connect to Oracle from Quantum GIS. 
I am trying *Layer -> Add vector layer -> Database New*. 
There are some Database connection types like ODBC, MSSQL, OGDI Vectors etc. but not Oracle.

Comment: supposedly you should start here:
http://www.cprogramto.com/download-and-install-quantum-gis-qgis-with-oracle-connectivity/

but it's not clear how you'd do this with an existing install

Comment: Also it is possible to connect to the Oracle DB by using ODBC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873160/connect-to-an-oracle-db-using-odbc

Comment: no idea, I want an answer to this question too-

Comment: I assume you are on Linux (Oracle support in QGIS seems only to be available on Windows out of the box). I think you first need to install the Oracle Instant Client, then you will need to compile GDAL with Oracle support yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft ODBC for Oracle.
But odac install your computer